# How to get the unique values

Tags: pandas

I have this df:

```
 data = pd.read_csv('attacks.csv', encoding="latin-1")
 new_data = data.loc[:,'Name':'Investigator or Source']
 new_data.head(5)

 Name   Sex     Age     Injury  Fatal (Y/N)     Time    Species     Investigator or Source
 0  Julie Wolfe     F   57  No injury to occupant, outrigger canoe and  pad...  N   18h00   White shark     R. Collier, GSAF
 1  Adyson McNeely  F   11  Minor injury to left thigh  N   14h00 -15h00    NaN     K.McMurray, TrackingSharks.com
 2  John Denges     M   48  Injury to left lower leg from surfboard skeg    N   07h45   NaN     K.McMurray, TrackingSharks.com
 3  male    M   NaN     Minor injury to lower leg   N   NaN     2 m shark   B. Myatt, GSAF
 4  Gustavo Ramos   M   NaN     Lacerations to leg & hand shark PROVOKED INCIDENT   N   NaN     Tiger shark, 3m     A .Kipper
```

How can I get the unique values ​​of the 'Species' category?
 I'm trying with:

```
 new_data["Species"].unique()
```

But it does not work.

Thank you!

Comment: Please post dataframes as text not images.  Also, what is currently wrong with your approach?

Comment: What is `print (new_data.columns.tolist())` ? Maybe some problem with column name `Species`

Comment: Hi Oscar. Please check if `Species` is actually the name of your columns. If you have a whitespace in the string, such as `" Species"`, then `new_data["Species"]` would not work (you'd have to access using `new_data[" Species"]` instead)

Comment: Ok, solved. I have a whitespace in the string. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

you can also try:

```
uniqueSpecies = set(new_data["Species"])
```

in case you wanna drop NaN

```
uniqueSpecies = set(new_data["Species"].dropna())
```

Comment: Thanks Leo. But using:  
     uniqueSpecies = set(new_data["Species"])
I get the same error:
     KeyError: 'Species'

Comment: Check the spelling of `Species` in your `dataframe`.